# Dataset that contains customer support interaction

Tags: data-request, nlp

I am looking for datasets containing customer support interaction. Not any aggregated statistics (resolution time, survey results), but the actually written emails/chat messages between customers and support assistants. IT forums could be helpful as well, but I don't know any that provide a dataset with the QAs.

I tried Google DatasetSearch, but I wasn't able to find exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I've just I found other similar questions posted, I think NLTK should have what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Bitext’s Customer Support Dataset](https://blog.bitext.com/free-customer-support-dataset)

---

Bitext’s Synthetic Data technology— completely for free! It contains over 8,000 utterances from 27 common intents —password recovery, delivery options, track refund, registration issues, etc.—, grouped in 11 major categories. The format is very straightforward, with text files with fields separated by commas). It includes language register variations such as politeness, colloquial style, swearing, indirect style, etc.

You can download it, import it to your favourite platform, and start discovering how Synthetic Training Data can help you get your bot up and running in a matter of minutes!

[**Download**](https://blog.bitext.com/cs/c/?cta_guid=1d729875-a124-4c6c-b4e3-4fb02f392a72&signature=AAH58kFkqMMc1ZOtGQyVp_Q-cm1Jx94loQ&pageId=23770464491&placement_guid=ccdc9c01-5398-45ca-aa90-398f0dcf5907&click=226aa3b7-e699-443c-ac76-6b224c4e4958&hsutk=d2d115443ddd7b7be321d1127a1eb6e4&canon=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.bitext.com%2Ffree-customer-support-dataset&portal_id=2396105&redirect_url=APefjpHY0MTlSFhJZGlednRxOoy98cCmZbD0eM9r4qdfCEjIW0ei0xAYr34rKFx_OqRqRE6wKHoz59uar2HF6rmjKLsbRtjSueT10nv16E17pCYwRRCDeqWcaMRZpjxWeT1_R75X_oQo&__hstc=153079206.d2d115443ddd7b7be321d1127a1eb6e4.1649519205649.1649519205649.1649519205649.1&__hssc=153079206.1.1649519205650&__hsfp=4193594878&contentType=blog-post)

---

#### [Relational Strategies in Customer Service (RSiCS) Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/veeralakrishna/relational-strategies-in-customer-servicersics)

Human-computer data from three live customer service Intelligent Virtual Agents (IVAs) in the domains of travel and telecommunications were collected, and annotators marked all text that was deemed unnecessary to the determination of user intention. After merging the selections of multiple annotators to create highlighted texts, a s second round of annotation was performed to determine the classes of language present in the highlighted sections such as the presence of Greetings, Backstory, Justification, Gratitude, Rants, or Emotions. This resulting corpus is a valuable resource for improving the quality and relational abilities of IVAs.

#### Data

Data was collected from four sources. The conversation logs of three commercial customer service IVAs and the Airline forums on TripAdvisor.com during August 2016.

Dataset numbering used in files:

- TripAdvisor.com airline forum
- Train travel IVA
- Airline travel IVA
- Telecommunications support IVA